# Find the critical points of $f(x,y) = \sin(x)+\sin(y) + \sin(x+y)$

Tags: real-analysis

I am stuck with the following exercise:

> Let $0 \le x \le 2\pi$. Find the critical points of $$f(x,y) = \sin(x)+\sin(y) + \sin(x+y)$$
>   and determine their type.

I calculated the gradient as follows:

$$\nabla f(x,y) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(x)+\cos(x+y)\\
\cos(y)+\cos(x+y) 
\end{bmatrix}$$

But now I do not know how to find $(x,y)$ such that $\nabla f(x,y) = 0.$ Could you help me?

Comment: $x = y = \pi$ look like good candidates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By cancelling the gradient,

$$\cos x=\cos y$$ and $$y=\pm x.$$

The minus sign yields

$$\cos x+1=0.$$

With the plus sign,

$$\cos x+\cos2x=0.$$

Then

$$\cos x+2\cos^2x-1=0$$ is quadratic in $\cos x$.